# Compare and Swap : synchronizing via different data sizes

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic

Using the GCC builtin C atomic primitives, we can perform an atomic CAS operation using `__atomic_compare_exchange`.

Unlike C++11's `std::atomic` type, the GCC C atomic primitives operate on regular non-atomic integral types, including 128-bit integers on platforms where `cmpxchg16b` is supported.  (A future version of the C++ standard may support similar functionality with the `std::atomic_view` class template.)

This makes me question:

What happens if an atomic CAS operation on a larger data size observes a change which happened by an atomic operation on the same memory location, but using a smaller data size?

For example, suppose we have:

```
struct uint128_type {
  uint64_t x;
  uint64_t y;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

And suppose we have a shared variable of type `uint128_type`, like:

```
uint128_type Foo;
```

Now, suppose Thread A does:

```
    Foo expected = { 0, 0 };
    Foo desired = { 100, 100 };
    int result = __atomic_compare_exchange(
        &Foo, 
        &expected, 
        &desired, 
        0, 
        __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST
    );
```

And Thread B does:

```
    uint64_t expected = 0;
    uint64_t desired = 500;
    int result = __atomic_compare_exchange(
        &Foo.x, 
        &expected, 
        &desired, 
        0, 
        __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST
    );
```

What happens if Thread A's 16-byte CAS happens before Thread B's 8 byte CAS (or vice-versa)?  Does the CAS fail as normal?  Is this even defined behavior?  Is this likely to "do the right thing" on typical architectures like x86_64 that support 16b CAS?

**Edit**: to be clear, since it seems to be causing confusion, I'm *not* asking if the above behavior is defined by the C++ standard.  Obviously, all the `__atomic_`* functions are GCC extensions.  (However future C++ standards may have to define this sort of thing, if `std::atomic_view` becomes standardized.)  I am asking more generally about the semantics of atomic operations on typical modern hardware.  As an example, if x86_64 code has 2 threads perform atomic operations on the same memory address, but one thread uses `CMPXCHG8b` and the other uses `CMPXCHG16b`, so that one  does an atomic CAS on a single word while the other does an atomic CAS on a double word, how are the semantics of these operations defined? More specifically, would a `CMPXCHG16b` fail because it observes that the data has mutated from the expected value due to a previous `CMPXCHG8b`?

In other words, can two different CAS operations using two different data sizes (but the same starting memory address) safely be used to synchronize between threads?

Comment: "on the same memory location, but using a smaller word size." - Sounds like a violation of strict aliasing rule -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: Atomic operations cannot be pre-empted.

Comment: But operating on &Foo vs &Foo.x clearly is not.violating aliasing rules,  any more than if we pass &Foo to memcpy or &Foo.x to memcpy

Comment: @Olaf This behavior is undefined according to the C and C++ standards no matter what because they don't say what the semantics of `__atomic_compare_exchange` are.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: In this spirit, any use of POSIX would trigger undefined behavior as well.

Comment: @KemyLand That's correct. Using `dlsym` to get the address of a function is a classic example. According to the C standard, casting a `void *` to a function pointer is undefined. You have to let the semantics of the function supercede the language. The UB argument applies only to cases where it's pure C/C++ code or the semantics are not specified by some other standard or semantic rule.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The C standard very well allows for extensions. E.g. conversion between `void *` and function pointers is explicitly listed as a "common extension" in J.5.7 . The term "common" signals there are very well other extensions accepted like built-in functions and other libraries than libc does not make your code invoke UB - in context of your implementation/environment. Only in context of the standard.

Comment: I think this question have different answers for different hardware. Are you specifically interested in x86_64?

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov I don't think so. I think it's about the semantics of atomic operations, not how those operations are implemented on particular platforms.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz GCC extensions have no predefined semantics. I personally implemented atomic builtins in GCC backend for private hardware twice and both implementations would have different answers for author's question.

Comment: @Olaf There the C standard is documenting the fact that I'm also reporting -- that what things not defined by the C standard do or don't do are outside the scope of the C standard. Using anything not specified in the C standard triggers behavior that is not defined by the C standard. Any time we're talking about a compiler extension, a POSIX function, or anything else, pointing out that the C standard makes it UB is pointless unless the relevant documentation for that thing doesn't define the behavior either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One or the other happens first, and each operation proceeds according to its own semantics.

On x86 CPUs, both operations will require a lock on the same cache line held throughout the entire operation. So whichever one gets that lock first will not see any effects of the second operation and whichever one gets that lock second will see all the effects of the first operation. The semantics of both operations will be fully respected.

Other hardware may achieve this result some other way, but if it doesn't achieve this result, it's broken unless it specifies that it has a limitation.

Answer (score 4):

The atomic data will, eventually, located somewhere in the memory and all accesses to it (or to respective caches, when the operations are atomic) will be serialized. Since the CAS operation is supposed to be atomic, it will performed as a whole or not at all.

That being said, one of the operations will succeed, the second will fail. The order is non-deterministic.

From [x86 Instruction Set Reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG8B:CMPXCHG16B.html):

> This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically. To simplify the interface to the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle without regard to the result of the comparison. The destination operand is written back if the comparison fails; otherwise, the source operand is written into the destination. (The processor never produces a locked read without also producing a locked write.)

Clearly, both threads will attempt to locked-write after locked-read (when used with LOCK prefix, that is), which means only one of them will succeed in performing the CAS, the other will read already changed value.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of atomic is unlikely to change, emphasis mine

> In concurrent programming, an operation (or set of operations) is atomic, 
>   linearizable, indivisible or uninterruptible if it appears to
>   the rest of the system to occur instantaneously. Atomicity is a
>   **guarantee of isolation** from concurrent processes.

Your question asks...

> What happens if an atomic CAS operation on a larger data size observes
>   a change which happened by an atomic operation on the same memory
>   location, but using a smaller data size?

By definition no two overlapping regions of memory modified using atomic operations can mutate concurrently ie the two operations must happen linearly or their not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware is usually very conservative when checking for conflicts between potentially conflicting atomic operations. It may even happen that two CAS operations to two completely different, non-overlapping address ranges may be detected to conflict with each other.